# Can't run TeamCity custom scripts

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, teamcity, ubuntu-12.04

I created a new instance with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, installed all required packages (like Java, RVM and Ruby) and then downloaded and installed TeamCity 7.0.4

TeamCity is located in /home/ubuntu, but I startup the server as root after running "sudo su".

For some reason, I can't run my rake tests, because earlier steps (that are necessary) fails. Here it is part of the build log:

```
[Step 1/5] Starting: /home/ubuntu/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script3896719423178259098
[00:06:03][Step 1/5] in directory: /webserver/K2
[00:06:03][Step 1/5] /home/ubuntu/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script3896719423178259098: 1: /home/ubuntu/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script3896719423178259098: source: not found
[00:06:03][Step 1/5] /home/ubuntu/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script3896719423178259098: 2: /home/ubuntu/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script3896719423178259098: bundle: not found
[00:06:03][Step 1/5] Process exited with code 127
```

The first build step that i want to run is "bundle install"

I don't know why have this problem. In centos 5 i can run all those steps.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more info on how to actually add additional entries in the PATH in TeamCity is

- go to project configuration editing UI
- in configuration steps (on the right side), pick '#7 Build Parameters'
- click 'add new parameter', enter the name 'PATH', choose the Kind 'Environment variable' (name should change to env.PATH in the name input field), and in value input field, append the path you need to the existing PATH variable (e.g. `%env.PATH%:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin`); save

That should be it, try running your task

Comment: This just saved me a lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no "bundle" in your PATH, you could check your PATH in agent parameters page and append right path if it's true.